# Calling SSJS from inside a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, ssjs

Does anyone have any clever ways to execute SSJS from within a journey?  I have some ideas but would love to hear yours.  My use case is to listen for new Salesforce CRM records to be created.  When they're created, kick off the journey - all that's fine, we can do that through Salesforce Data entry event.  But, what I want to do is when a new record is created to make an SSJS call to pull out a specific URL within a field on that object, make an external API call to Rebrandly to shorten the URL and update the object.  I should be able to do this by mocking up an email and including AMPScript in that email to make an HTTPGet call to a CloudPage, and on the CloudPage I'll do my SSJS work.  But, it's real hacky.  I would have to basically write the AMPScript and then after the HTTPGet call, do a RaiseError() to cancel out of the email send.  Oh, and choose a dummy email address that the journey will "send to".  Does anyone have any other "better" ways to do this?

Comment: I would do exactly what you said, but instead of RaiseError (which you would get charged for) I would put something like `1 == 1` in the exclusion script box for that email activity to cancel the send (which you won’t get charged for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this. The **best approach** would be to build a custom activity, but the following approach should work:

Create a script activity containing your SSJS and save it as a code snippet*, with the following code:

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

// insert your script here

Write(1); // outputs 1 for exclusion script
</script>
```

Next, add a Send Email Activity to your journey that just uses an empty email, but you might want to include `%%[RaiseError('do not send!')]%%` in the email just to be absolutely certain that the email is not sent under any circumstances (for example, if someone accidentally deletes `Write(1);` in the code snippet).

Now, in the exclusion script field of the Send Email Activity, enter the following:

```ampscript
TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey("insert-code-snippet-external-key"))==1
```

This will force the SSJS in the code snippet to be intepreted, and as it always return `1`, the email won't be sent.

**Note: use a code snippet over another content block type, as all other content blocks are wrapped in HTML tables.*